# In photoshop (CC), is there a way to apply the changes made to one CR2 (.xmp) to all my other (.CR2) photos?

Tags: raw, camera

Editing pictures in CR2 and after applying a few hours of settings to one picture, I would want all my other pictures to have that same setting applied to. Possible? Is there a way around using the Camera Raw plugin in Photoshop?

Please help!

Comment: Are the changes done only in Adobe Camera RAW or also in Photoshop?

Comment: I opened my CR2, and it uses Photoshop's Camera raw plugin 10.4. I cannot open multiple CR2s at the same time. If I try to, it will open them one by one but never in the same window....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is NO WAY to batch edit CR2s having done the changes one one (and having a xmp file) without using Bridge.

It used to work like that before in Camera RAW, IT DOESN'T anymore. Do not loose time into trying to make it work like good old times, I guess that,s why there's Bridge. At least it's free. Thanks Adobe.

;)

PS: Special thanks to Romeo trying to troubleshoot this!

Answer (score 3):

You can sync all the settings (nondestructive one) in ACR (Adobe Camera RAW) by selecting the image you edit, then select also all the images you want to apply and right click->Sync Setting. Or press Alt-S. Select what you want to sync (exposure, contrast, white balance, etc.) and press OK.

If you have open in ACR only the image in question just press Done and then open all the images you want to sync including edited one. Make sure the image in question have blue border around (to be source for settings). And then do the sync as described above.

Comment: I can't open another image then the one that's opened. I tried right-clicking, does nothing, I can't get multiple images to open in the same window as my ACR window, even If I select multiple then open them in Photoshop, it just opens one picture at the time...

Comment: Have you try with drag and drop the RAW images in empty PS screen?

Comment: Yes it opens them one by one... I just want to apply my xmp to all my CR2s, I don,t understand why it's so complicated

Comment: Okok I got, no way to do it directly in Camera RAW, you have to use Bridge. Thanks anyway Romeo.